# Using build variables with jenkins' build steps

Tags: jenkins, devops

I use "free style project" to get build of my project. 
I select "This project is parameterized" and define "choice parameter".
[Project choice parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS9eI.png)

Then i define build step which has string match condition with `${Project}` build parameter.

**Build gives error with following console output:**

> Run condition [Strings match] enabling prebuild for step [BuilderChain]
>   Exception caught evaluating condition: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Unrecognized macro 'Project' in '${Project}'], action = [Fail]

How can i use build parameter with logical build conditons.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure its not something related with this [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482183/jenkins-conditional-build-step-gitlastcommit-git-commit)

Otherwise you can use plugin [Conditional Build Step plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) to compare if your parameter matches a string, and it should work fine as you use it with `${Project}`.
If you are using parameter on a another kind of build step like 'Execute shell command' or 'Execute shell command on Windows' use `${Project}`on *nix systems and `%Project%`for Windows systems

Another way (that works) to get a build parameter and compare it to a string if you are using a pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters{
      choice(
        choices: 'PROJECT_1\nPROJECT_2',
        description: 'Select the project',
        name: 'Project')
  }
  stages {
      stage ('Test stage') {
          when {
              expression { params.Project == 'PROJECT_1' }
          }
          steps {
              echo "IT IS PROJECT 1"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I install "Conditional Build Step plugin" and it works, thank you. But ${xxx} format does not work with windows installation and "Execute windows batch command" step. I also tried with container installation which comes with linux "execute shell" step, it worked.

Comment: If you are using "Execute windows batch command", paramaters have to be used with the syntax %PARAMETER%, syntax with $ is for *nix systems.